# VBA - Store an array inside of a class - Type mismatch

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class

I've been searching all over but nothing seems to do the trick for me. Here is the problem:

I want to store an array of "keys"
Here is my simple class:

```
Private pkeys_length As Integer
Private pkeys() As String
Public Property Get keys_length() As Integer
    keys_length = pkeys_length
End Property
Public Property Let keys_length(arg As Integer)
    pkeys_length = arg
End Property
Public Property Get Keys() As String
    Keys = pkeys()
End Property
Public Property Let Keys(ByVal arg As String)
    ReDim pkeys(0 To pkeys_length) As String
    pkeys = arg
End Property
```

And here is what I am trying to store:

```
Dim str_pkeys() As String
Dim pkey_count As Integer
pkey_count = CountPrimaryKeys(stbl)
'Store the keys of that table
ReDim str_pkeys(pkey_count) As String
keyset_1.keys_length = pkey_count
str_pkeys = FindPrimaryKeys(keyset_1.Table)
keyset_1.Keys = str_pkeys
```

As it stands, it Gives the error `Compile Error: Type mismatch`
I have had several problems while storing the array, I'm not sure if I am actually getting anywhere. This is the only error I haven't been able to fix. All I need to be able to do is store the array of strings in the class.

Anyone familiar with how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to  use `String()` in your Get property and remove the `ByVal` in the Let:

```
Private pkeys_length As Integer
Private pkeys() As String

Public Property Get keys_length() As Integer
    keys_length = pkeys_length
End Property

Public Property Let keys_length(arg As Integer)
    pkeys_length = arg
End Property
Public Property Get Keys() As String()
    Keys = pkeys
End Property

Public Property Let Keys(arg() As String)
    ReDim pkeys(0 To pkeys_length) As String
    pkeys = arg
End Property
```

Apart from this a small design suggestion: do you really need a Set for the array length? Why not include this in the set of the array - and only provide the Get instead?

Comment: Thanks for for that, it worked! And I'm just fiddling around with different features - of classes in VBA - can't ever learn enough ;). How would I go about including it in the set of the array? Thanks again Peter.

Comment: `Public Property Let Keys(arg() As String)
    ReDim pkeys(0 To pkeys_length) As String
    pkeys = arg
    pkeys_length = FunctionToDetermineLenghthLikeUBoundHere(arg)
End Property`